# Language store switcher redirect on home page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.9

I have five language store switcher drop-down

EN store is my base store

when click on cms page then showing cms page with content

after cms page when click on different store (FR) then its redirect on home page

I have already created store wise cms page

anyone can help me in this how to redirect with correct cms page with store wise

anyone help here, thanks in advance